# How to add images from a database together if they have the same foreign key

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So my problem is i am exporting images from a table called "BikeImages" within this table theres images that our under the same foreign Key BikeCode. How do i make sure the images are added together instead of seperately.

For Example

BikeCode: 123

BikeImages: IMAGE1, IMAGE2

BikeCode: 14

BikeImages IMAGE1

```
 <?php
            $sql1 = "SELECT BikeCode, Manufacturer, Model, SubType, Year, FrameMaterial, Description, Gender, Type, Price, Stock FROM Bike WHERE Stock > 0";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
            while(list($bikecode, $manufacturer, $model, $subtype, $year, $fmaterial, $desc, $gender, $type, $price, $stock) = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {            

                echo "
                <table>
                <tr><th>BikeCode:</th>
                <th>Manufacturer:</th>
                <th>Model:</th>
                <th>Subtype:</th>
                <th>Year:</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>$bikecode</td>
                <td>$manufacturer</td>
                <td>$model</td>
                <td>$subtype</td>
                <td>$year</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>FrameMaterial:</th>
                <th>Gender:</th>
                <th>Type:</th>
                <th>Price:</th>
                <th>Stock:</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>$fmaterial</td>
                <td>$gender</td>
                <td>$type</td>
                <td>£$price</td>
                <td>$stock</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><th>Description:</th><td colspan=\"4\">$desc</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Bike Images:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"$sourcepath\" title=\"$description\"><img src=\"$sourcepath\" width=\"72\" height=\"72\" /></a></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Order Now:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"basket.php?action=add&id=$bikecode\">Add To Cart</a></td></tr>
                 </table>";
            }
      ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: I have to combine this code with the above code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT SourcePath, Description, BikeCode FROM BikeImages order by bikecode";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$previous = -1;
echo "<table>";
while(list($sourcepath, $description, $bcode) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    // if bikecode changed, append "Order now"
    if ($previous != -1 && $previous != $bcode) {
        echo "<tr><th>Order Now:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"basket.php?action=add&id=$previous\">Add To Cart</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr><th>Bike Images:</th><td colspan=\"4\">";
    echo "<a href=\"$sourcepath\" title=\"$description\"><img src=\"$sourcepath\" width=\"72\" height=\"72\" /></a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    $previous = $bcode;
}

echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: `order by BikeCode`, so all related images appear together in the results?

Comment: Do you have multiple bikeimages in one row separated by comma?

Comment: @MarcB Yes, i believe thats what i need I shall try that out.

Comment: No did not work. Help would be really appreciated. @OlafDietsche no, all my bikeimages are in seperate rows.

Comment: Create function taking `bikecode` as parameter and returning the HTML TABLE with all images (do select WHERE BikeCode = parameter)... then loop thru all bikes you want to display and in the look call the function returning the complete table with all images

Comment: @KamilŠrot I am not to sure how to do that. Can you possible assist me? i am still new to PHP.

Comment: @Moe just start following the description and ask questions, when you get stuck. It doesn't make sense to write code for you - you'll learn nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the table tag in the loop, but outside

```
<?php
    // if bikecode changed, append "Order now"
    if ($previous != -1 && $previous != $bikecode) {
        echo "<tr><th>Order Now:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"basket.php?action=add&id=$previous\">Add To Cart</a></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr><th>Bike Images:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"$sourcepath\" title=\"$description\"><img src=\"$sourcepath\" width=\"72\" height=\"72\" /></a></td></tr>";
    $previous = $bikecode;
}

echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

With the two selects, you have an outer loop going through bikes and an inner loop iterating over the images. An "easy" but expensive solution, could be

```
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT BikeCode, Manufacturer, Model, SubType, Year, FrameMaterial, Description, Gender, Type, Price, Stock FROM Bike WHERE Stock > 0";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die('Query1 failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));
echo "<table>";
while(list($bikecode, $manufacturer, $model, $subtype, $year, $fmaterial, $desc, $gender, $type, $price, $stock) = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {
    echo "<tr><th>BikeCode:</th>
          <th>Manufacturer:</th>
          <th>Model:</th>
          <th>Subtype:</th>
          <th>Year:</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>$bikecode</td>
          <td>$manufacturer</td>
          <td>$model</td>
          <td>$subtype</td>
          <td>$year</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>FrameMaterial:</th>
          <th>Gender:</th>
          <th>Type:</th>
          <th>Price:</th>
          <th>Stock:</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>$fmaterial</td>
          <td>$gender</td>
          <td>$type</td>
          <td>£$price</td>
          <td>$stock</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><th>Description:</th><td colspan=\"4\">$desc</td></tr>\n";

    $sql = "SELECT SourcePath, Description FROM BikeImages where bikecode = '$bikecode'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Query2 failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    while(list($sourcepath, $description) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
          <tr><th>Bike Images:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"$sourcepath\" title=\"$description\"><img src=\"$sourcepath\" width=\"72\" height=\"72\" /></a></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr><th>Order Now:</th><td colspan=\"4\"><a href=\"basket.php?action=add&id=$bikecode\">Add To Cart</a></td></tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Hey, That does work however when combining it with the other Code it does not work i have edited the above post.

Comment: It doesn't work. i think it is because forgotten to add this information $sql = "SELECT SourcePath, Description, BikeCode FROM BikeImages order by bikecode";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); You have selected the information from Bike table but not from BikeImages.

Comment: @Moe Yes, I didn't look at the different SQL statement. I thought it's just a bit modified from your first one. So, this is now a different question. You must either do a second query or join between the two. Either way, it becomes a bit more complicated than your original question.

Comment: Yh, That's why i've been so stuck on it. How would i do a joint query and a second query wouldn't work because i would have to do another while loop correct?

Comment: @Moe You must do an inner loop either way, because it is a one to many relation, it seems. For every bike you have several images.

Comment: @Moe Look at the updated answer. When I understood it right, it should do what you need.

Comment: Firstly, i would like to thank you alot for constantly giving this a go. However, it hasn't worked this error came up. Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /homes/2012/abpr904/html/velocity/test.php on line 38 This is line 38  while(list($sourcepath, $description) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

Comment: @Moe Added simple error checking for the queries. Please look again.

Comment: It says Query2 failed: Unknown column 'BRPR2012' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Moe Oops, stupid me, I thought bikecode is an `int`. Anyway, I've put quotes around `$bikecode`. Next try.